# Sphinx autodoc replace standard :members:

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

So I am determine to make such thing:

I need

```
.. automodule:: main
   :members:
```

but with functionality of

```
This is my caption
------------------

.. autodata:: CAPTION

   About my caption
```

So, I need to write something about each function, method and class, but alongside I need that all the new function I've created in a code will appear in docs without editing the docs. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/autodoc.html):

Members without docstrings will be left out, unless you give the undoc-members flag option:

```
.. automodule:: noodle
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
```

Also, “Private” members (that is, those named like _private or __private) will be included if the private-members flag option is given and Python “special” members (that is, those named like __special__) will be included if the special-members flag option is given:

```
.. autoclass:: my.Class
   :members:
   :private-members:
   :special-members:
```

And finally! It’s possible to override the signature for explicitly documented callable objects (functions, methods, classes) with the regular syntax that will override the signature gained from introspection:

```
.. autoclass:: Noodle(type)

   .. automethod:: eat(persona)
```

There are a lot more useful information in the link I posted in the beginning of the answer. Have a look at it for more advanced ways of documenting your code.

Comment: already read this page 10 times upside down, as well as other pages at sphinx wiki + tons of stackoverflow threads :) Maybe I asked it wrong, what I want to do is use :members: (and maybe :undoc-members:) so that when I add code to my project - it will appear at sphinx-documentation without my interference. But I also need to be able to ADD some info to each class/function/variable, because I like clean code without comments and there're almost no docstrings in my project.

Comment: also, I have just noticed that all my variables within methods was completely ignored by sphinx... that's kind of strange and bad, because I have one class and lots of functions within it, which contain important cycles and variables

Comment: If you're the only one who reads your code, then having no docstrings is probably ok, but actually it's a bad practice. Many programmers read the code first, and documentation second, so consider having at least some basic docstrings which at least will describe what this thing is doing, avoiding obvious of course. Also, :members: and :undoc-members: will do exactly what your want. If that doesn't work for you, you have problem somewhere else, do you get any errors while generating documentation ? Also Sphinx won't document your cycles and other logic inside a function, only it's signature.

Answer (score 2):

As I was searching around for a solution to including all modules, methods, functions that I have in code to the documentation I stumbled on this question.

I'm not sure if it's what you are looking for, but it solved my problem, and it's included here for any one who might find it useful [Github HyperSpy Repo](https://github.com/hyperspy/hyperspy/blob/RELEASE_next_minor/doc/generate_api_doc.sh)

Has a nice little bash script that will screen the code and write the proper

```
.. automodule
```

for each module out there in your source tree, hope that helps